# React Good Practices For Handling DOM Elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

Is it a good practice to use the Javascript DOM in React e.g

```
import React, { useState } from "react"

function Form() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("")
  let form = document.getElementById("name")
  function addName() {
    setName(form)
  }
}
```

Comment: Not really. The changes made by direct DOM manipulation will typically be overwritten on the next render. Please add more details because *maybe* you have a use case, but probably not.

Comment: @zero298 I am trying to create a video player in React, whereby a user can like, dislike, remove and add to the playlist. So when I like 1 video all the videos are being liked. My idea was to use the DOM to target 1 video only with the id being the same as the video key which is unique.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it a good practice to use the Javascript DOM in React e.g

Short answer: No.

---

Long Answer: *Almost never.*

At best you can `useRef`

```
const formRef = useRef()

function onSubmit() {
  console.log(formRef.current)
}

return <form ref={formRef} onSubmit={onSubmit} />
```

`useRef` does have a lot of perfectly valid use cases. But that's best avoided as well, if there's another way.

There are some *very* rare cases where you may need to do something like `document.getElementById()`, but they are highly unusual. You don't need to touch the DOM directly unless you've exhausted all other possibilities and you are trying to do something very non-idomatic.

---

In React, your presentation is entirely derived from your state. It's a one way flow. You may handle events from the user by updating state, which then causes a fresh render with that new state.

If you are diving into the DOM directly then you break this flow, things get hard to debug, react may do weird things. You're in uncharted territory with no guarantees about how things may behave.

Comment: Thanks let me have a look at the useRef hook

Answer (score 0):

No, you can use useState or useRef hooks to get dom elements in a much better and cleaner way.
I personally like useState more and this is an example of how

import it

```
import React, {useState} from "react"
```

set it up

```
const [name, setName] = useState("")
```

The jsx

```
return (
<form>
<input type="text" value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
</form>
)
```

First you import it and set it up. name is the variable with the value of "". setName is a function which changes the name variable. When name changes it renders the whole component again, which is great. You set the value of the input to name which starts as "" and whenever you write something setName will fire off which will change name to be whatever you wrote which will update the value in the input element.

Then you can do whatever you want with the name value.